# Text in Shopping Cart page is not uppercase?

Tags: shopping-cart

I want to change shopping cart to Shopping Cart, unit price to Unit Price, remove to Remove,... How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open the file

```
/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

All the labels that you mentioned are there. You can change them directly in this file to whatever text or case you like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use css for this purprose:

`.your-identifier {text-transform: capitalize;}`

Comment: Thank you, but where can I edit the css file?

Comment: You will find the css files in `skin/frontend/default/yourtheme/css` or in `skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/css`

Comment: Most likely the identifier will be `#shopping-cart-table th span`, but this depends on the theme itself.